# Use dd or redirection to write to tape?

Tags: tape, dd

My Googling for writing to tapes with encryption have turned up various results.

Most along the lines of piping tar to openssl similar to:

```
tar cf - /home | openssl des3 -salt -k "Your-Password-Here"
```

Some then pipe to dd, while other just redirect to the tape device:

```
tar cf - /home | openssl des3 -salt -k "Your-Password-Here" | dd of=/dev/nst0
tar cf - /home | openssl des3 -salt -k "Your-Password-Here" > /dev/nst0
```

**Question:** is there a particular reason to invoke dd for this, or is it safe to just stream "directly" to the tape with a redirection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, tape devices like being written to in blocks, so using `dd` is probably better than just redirecting output.  However, your `dd` command as written won't do blocking.  Depending on your tape device, the block size may be vastly different, but a block size of 4k was(*) typical and would be specified by using `bs=4096` in the `dd` command list.  Eg: `dd of=/dev/rst0 bs=4096`

However, googling one of many LTO tape drives recommend a block size of not greater than 256kb.  So read / research the best size for your device.  You may also be able to use scaling abbreviations on the `bs` argument: `bs=4k` or `bs=1M`.

Comment: I thought it may be something like that; your answer is clear and concise. It's a HP Ultrium 1760; I'll look into finding it's preferred block size. Thank-you :)

Comment: In the past it had been advisable to note the blocksize being used, too, specifically when trying to read back the tape ;-)